# Reading JSON from <script> Tag

Tags: javascript, json, object

How can I get JSON data embedded in a script tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="data" type="application/json">{org: 10, items:['one','two']}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var obj = JSON.parse( document.getElementById('data').value );
            console.log( obj );
            console.log( obj.org );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<script>` elements are not form controls. They don't have `value` properties (so. when you read it, you get `undefined` which is `"undefined"` when cast to a string, and that isn't valid JSON).

Read the content of the text node inside the element instead.

You also need to write JSON instead of a JavaScript object literal.

- Property names must be strings, not identifiers.
- Strings must be quoted with `"` not `'`.

```html
<script id="data" type="application/json">{"org": 10, "items":["one","two"]}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').firstChild.data);
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(obj.org);
</script>
```

Comment: Why is firstChild used when the script tag has no children elements, just the data?

Comment: @GTSJoe — To access the text node inside the element node.

Comment: Is there an advantage to that over just using document.getElementById('data').text?

Answer (score 0):

The `u` comes from "undefined". Try:

```
JSON.parse( document.getElementById('data').innerHTML );
```

...but keep in mind that your current input is not JSON. So correctly formatted it would be:

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">{"org":10,"items":["one","two"]}</script>
```