# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get my json file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="data/covers/covers.json"></script>`

But in the console I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`
in `covers.json:2`

my json file:

```
{
    "covers":["text.jpg", "text.jpg", "text.jpg", "text.jpg", "text.jpg"]
}
```

what is the problem here? I can't seem to understand.

Comment: It should be assigned to a variable and consumed that may be via URL call. I am not sure what is meaning of writing it in script tag with type="text/javascript"

Comment: Have you tried `type="text/json"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from <script> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915805/reading-json-from-script-tag)

Comment: @Amith yes using ```type="text/json``` worked

Comment: Yow bro! 
MimeType is vowing the problem, when the browser requests the json file it is expecting to get a text/JavaScript. But it is not a JavaScript file . You need to change the type to application/json

Comment: You can’t load a file containing json using a `script` tag. If you need to load the contents of a file containing JSON you need to issue a http request using e.g. the fetch api.

Comment: Changing `text/javascript` to `text/json` will remove the error, but it won’t allow to load JSON with `script` tag and `src`

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type=“application/json”> {“troll”:”hellos”}</script>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  -->
</body>
</html>



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type=“application/json”> 
    {“troll”:”hellos”}
    </script>
    <script >
    console.log("a")
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is you dumn ? why did you dislike it ?

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: And you can't use "smart quotes" in code.